# Router.go is not working

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a meteor app. I built the layout and the application using [Material Design Lite](http://www.getmdl.io/) by google. Following is my navigation:

**navigation html**

```
<template name="nav">
    <nav class="mdl-navigation mdl-layout--large-screen-only">
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="" id="home">Home</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="" id="my-pictures">My Pictures</a>
    </nav>
</template>
```

**router file**

```
passIfLoggedIn = ->
    if not Meteor.user()
        @render 'login'
    else
        @next()

Router.route '/home',
    waitOn: -> Meteor.subscribe 'StaticTexts'
    action: ->
        @layout 'layout'
        @render 'openPictures', to: 'content'
        @render 'cover', to: 'cover'
    onBeforeAction: passIfLoggedIn

Router.route '/myPictures',
    waitOn: -> Meteor.subscribe 'StaticTexts'
    action: ->
        @layout 'layout'
        @render 'myPictures', to: 'content'
    onBeforeAction: passIfLoggedIn
```

**handler**

```
Template.adminNav.events
    'click #home': (e) ->
        console.log "home"
        Router.go '/home'
    'click #my-pictures': (e) ->
        console.log "my pictures"
        Router.go '/myPictures'
```

The problem here is when I navigate to individual route for browser url, it renders just as expected. But when I click on the navigation panel to the other button, for eg: `My Pictures`, the url in the address bar changes momentarily and reverts back to present route. The page stays unchanged. It does not navigate to other page. Can somebody help me out with this?

**EDIT 1 typo in the question.** 
**handler**

```
Template.nav.events
    'click #home': (e) ->
        console.log "home"
        Router.go '/home'
    'click #my-pictures': (e) ->
        console.log "my pictures"
        Router.go '/myPictures'
```

Comment: Why not just use `href="{{pathFor 'home'}}"` to put real links in your nav instead of handling click events in js?

Comment: thank you. that did the trick.

Comment: This has the extra benefit of allowing links to be spidered (assuming you have spiderable installed). Better for SEO.

Comment: @MichelFloyd but i thought now googlebots crawled javascripts as well?

Comment: You have to install spiderable and phantomjs for it to work on Meteor sites. You might want to read [Google's spec](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more) but  don't believe that it will follow click events to their logical conclusion, that's asking a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using different template names to make use of the events.
So you are binding the click events to the **adminNav** template, while you want them in the **nav** template.

Try this instead

```
Template.nav.events
```

**Edit to yours:**

The Router.go has a lower priority than the empty href atrribute of the link, so he jumps into the function of your event, but skips the Router.go and route you to href="" instead.

```
<a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="" id="home">Home</a>
```

should be

```
<a class="mdl-navigation__link" id="home">Home</a>
```

You need to style the link otherwise tho.

**Edit 2:**

Sindis is right, you can use e.preventDefault() in your click event.

```
Template.adminNav.events
    'click #home': (e) ->
        e.preventDefault
        console.log "home"
        Router.go '/home'
    'click #my-pictures': (e) ->
        e.preventDefault
        console.log "my pictures"
        Router.go '/myPictures'
```

This does the trick too.

Comment: sorry, that was a typo here.

Comment: I see, I tried to test it on my machine. Router.go doesn't work when the a tag has a "href" attribute set. The empty href has a higher priority than the Router.go function so he redirects you to the currently opened page.

Comment: If there is href, e.preventDefault() at start should do the work